# How to create a custom id using auto increment at the time of table creation in My SQL

Tags: mysql, uid

Is there a way to set at the time of creating a table a custom ID with some character as prefix and the rest are numbers which is auto incremented so that the first time a record is inserted the ID will be "UID0000001" and the second time a record is inserted the ID will be "UID0000002" and so on automatically in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the prefix would always be `UID`, then you should just maintain an auto increment `id` column and then build the `UIDxxxxx` value when you query or in your presentation layer.  If the prefix could vary, then you would need to state the rules if you want a concrete answer.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    some_col varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    -- other columns here
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

SELECT CONCAT('UID', LPAD(id, 7, '0')) AS uid
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: And how exactly do I achieve that at the time of creating a table. Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Instead of adding the prefix at the time of fetching the data I want to store the data at the time of inserting a record.

Comment: No you don't.  There is no point to doing that.  If you must, then use the trigger option in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the database via a trigger. What you would need to do is to use an auto_increment-column and get the value of it in the BEFORE-trigger:

```
delimiter $$
drop table thetable
$$
create table thetable (
id int auto_increment,
id_text varchar(20),
another varchar(20),
primary key(id),
unique index(id_text)
)
$$

CREATE TRIGGER thetable_ibefore
BEFORE INSERT ON thetable
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  

DECLARE v_id int;

select auto_increment into v_id
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = database() and table_name = 'thetable';

SET NEW.id_text = concat('UID',substr(concat('000000', v_id), -7)); 
END;
$$

insert into thetable (another) values ('ABC')
$$

select * from thetable
$$
```